# Cadastro no BD com campos pré preenchidos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou criando um sistema de cadastro em cima de um sistema que encontrei na net. No meu sistema só existe 2 campos e-mail e senha, sendo que a senha já vai estar pré cadastrada, faltando assim somente o usuário preencher o e-mail.
Estou com problemas na hora em que consulto o banco de dados, pois não consigo alimentar essa informação do e-mail, segue código onde tenho dúvida de como fazer essa consulta.

```
if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
// escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
    $user_email = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['user_email'], ENT_QUOTES));
    $user_password = $_POST['user_password_new'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_pass = '" . $user_password . "';";
    $query_check_user_password = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

    if ($query_check_user_password->num_rows == 1) {
        // check if user or email address already exists
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . $user_email . "';";
        $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

        if ($query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that email address is already taken.";
        } else {
            // write new user's data into database
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_pass, user_email) VALUES('" . $user_password . "', '" . $user_email . "');";
            $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if user has been added successfully
            if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                $this->messages[] = "Your account has been created successfully. You can now log in.";
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
            }
        }
    }else {
        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that password is invalid.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando vc tenta gravar um novo registro ele da erro ou valor do email é gravado em branco?

Comment: Ele da a mensagem "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again." Referente ao else {
                        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
                    }

Comment: Deixe seu código assim para exibir a mensagem de erro do banco `$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` se estiver usando as funções mysql_*, se for o mysqli utilize `mysqli_error($conexao)`

Comment: Uma pergunta, isso é por acaso um fluxo de alteração de senha onde informa a senha anterior e a nova senha?

Comment: Não, não é um fluxo de alteração de senha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem mas se o que você quer é somente inserir o email é assim:

```
 if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

    $user_email = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['user_email'], ENT_QUOTES));
    $user_password = $_POST['user_password_new'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_pass = '" . $user_password . "';";
    $query_check_user_password = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

    if ($query_check_user_password->num_rows == 1) {
        // check if user or email address already exists
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . $user_email . "';";
        $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

        if ($query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that email address is already taken.";
        } else {
            // write new user's data into database
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_email = '". $user_email . "' WHERE user_pass = '". $user_password ."';";
            $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if user has been added successfully
            if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                $this->messages[] = "Your account has been created successfully. You can now log in.";
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
            }
        }
    }else {
        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that password is invalid.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas antes de inserir o e-mail queria verificar se a senha que ele vai preencher no formulário é igual a que ta no banco cadastrada

Comment: a senha vai ser unica para cada registro ? se for ai você tem que dar update no email e não insert

Comment: cada usuário vai ter uma senha diferente, ele vai com essa senha no sistema e cadastra seu e-mail.

Comment: então é update mesmo, editei o código, ve se é isso mesmo

Comment: Deu certo é isso mesmo!